# Remove all points from polygon one by one

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm creating a feature of removing points from openlayers polygons when drawing. So there is my "configuration":

```
source = new ol.source.Vector({
    wrapX: false,
});

raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source,
    style: new ol.style.Style(/* some config */)
});

view = new ol.View({
    center: defaultLonLatFormat,
    zoom: 12
});

mapx = new ol.Map({
       layers: [raster, vector],
       target: 'target',
       view: view
});
```

Code used to start drawing:

```
draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
     source: source,
     type: 'Polygon',
});

mapx.addInteraction(draw);
```

Code used to remove last point:

```
draw.removeLastPoint();
draw.changed();
```

Everything works like a charm until polygon is open - until I connect last point with first point. After that removing last point makes nothing. Fortunatelly I can delete points with `alt + click` - it works until there is 3 points left which makes minimal closed polygon - triangle. Then even `alt + click` combination doesn't work. I've even tried this on [OpenLayers examples](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/modify-features.html) - this same behaviour. So I've got three questions:

1. What happens after closing polygon, so I can't delete points with `draw.removeLastPoint()`?
2. Why I'm unable to delete last three points from polygon?
3. Any ideas how to achieve such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

1. After the drawing is finished, [the sketch is added to the target layer](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.Draw.html#finishDrawing), and also removed from the draw interaction, so if you want to access it, you need to call

   > source.getFeatures();

any draw interaction functions do no longer have effect on it.

2. As written [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Polygon.html), Polygon is:

*Array of linear rings that define the polygon. The first linear ring of the array defines the outer-boundary or surface of the polygon. Each subsequent linear ring defines a hole in the surface of the polygon. A linear ring is an array of vertices' coordinates where the first coordinate and the last are equivalent.*

Technically, when the outer boundary is not a linear ring it is not a valid polygon. When you have less than three coordinates, it is more of a line.

3. You can check the number of points in the polygon geometry and when trying to delete the third point, change the geometry to line (or more preciesly to LineString), and when deleting the second point change it to point.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will check it on tuesday and will give You some feedback if it works.